# How to center a window properly in Java FX?

Tags: javafx

Java FX provides Window.centerOnScreen() to - guess what - center a window on a screen. HOWEVER, the Java FX' definition of "center of a screen" seems to be at (0.5x;0.33y). I hoped this was a bug, but [I was told it's not](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-40368).

Anyway. Has someone came up with a clean and easy solution on how to center a Window before displaying it? My first approach leads to flickering of the screen, since the window has to be displayed first, before it can be centered.

```
public static void centerOnScreen(Stage stage) {
  stage.centerOnScreen();
  stage.setY(stage.getY() * 3f / 2f);
}
```

**Update**:
What I forgot to mention; I don't know the size of the window beforehand, so in order to center it manually I have to display it first - what causes it to flicker one time. So I'm looking for a solution to center it without displaying it first - like Java FX is able to do it, however the wrong way.

Answer (score 19):

This is how you do it before the stage was made visible:

```
    double width = 640;
    double height = 480;

    Rectangle2D screenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
    stage.setX((screenBounds.getWidth() - width) / 2); 
    stage.setY((screenBounds.getHeight() - height) / 2);  

    final Scene scene = new Scene( new Group(), width, height);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
```

and this after the stage was made visible, i. e. you can use the properties of the stage:

```
    double width = 640;
    double height = 480;

    final Scene scene = new Scene( new Group(), width, height);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    Rectangle2D screenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
    stage.setX((screenBounds.getWidth() - stage.getWidth()) / 2); 
    stage.setY((screenBounds.getHeight() - stage.getHeight()) / 2);
```

If you have multiple screens, you can calculate the position manually using the list of Screen objects which is returned by the [Screen.getScreens()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Screen.html#getScreens%28%29) method.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to get the window width/height before displaying it first? I don't know its size. See question update.

Comment: Your response was brilliant. However, I just want to add a note for those of us that are new (myself included). You need to make certain the imports are AWT or JavaFX as appropriate to your application. Cheers

Answer (score 9):

The general trick to responding to initialization of a value is to create a listener for the property that removes itself when the property is initialized. So you can do

```
    Screen screen = Screen.getPrimary();
    Rectangle2D sbounds = screen.getBounds();

    double sw = sbounds.getWidth() ;
    double sh = sbounds.getHeight();

    listenToSizeInitialization(primaryStage.widthProperty(), 
            w -> primaryStage.setX(( sw - w) /2));
    listenToSizeInitialization(primaryStage.heightProperty(), 
            h -> primaryStage.setY(( sh - h) /2));


    primaryStage.show();
```

with

```
private void listenToSizeInitialization(ObservableDoubleValue size, 
        DoubleConsumer handler) {

    ChangeListener<Number> listener = new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> obs, 
                Number oldSize, Number newSize) {
            if (newSize.doubleValue() != Double.NaN) {
                handler.accept(newSize.doubleValue());
                size.removeListener(this);
            }
        }
    };
    size.addListener(listener);
}
```

Comment: FWIW I think the way it's done in the API method looks better - maybe that's just how I position myself in front of the screen. But they should at least document that that's what they're doing.

Answer (score 6):

I know this has post was answered about three and a half ages ago, but it seems to me that everybody has overlooked the problem.

you just need to type the `stage.centerOnScreen();` right after the `stage.show()` because if you write it before the code will be executed once and then it goes to its original state(that is how its explained in my head).

Comment: It doesn't look like you read and understood the problem. `centerOnScreen()` does *not* center on the screen, which is what this post is about.

Comment: it does for me. maybe you need to update your eclipse files

Answer (score 3):

for this code you have to import

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
```

then

```
Dimension d= Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize(); // get screen size
primaryStage.show(); //show stage because you wouldn't be able to get Height & width of the stage
primaryStage.setX(d.width/2-(primaryStage.getWidth()/2));
primaryStage.setY(d.height/2-(primaryStage.getHeight()/2));
```

if you want to do it before that stage is show then at the place of primaryStage.getWidth()/2 replace it with the height you gonna pass in scenes constructor.

```
primaryStage.setX(d.width/2-(300/2));
primaryStage.setY(d.height/2-(300/2));
Scene scene = new Scene(root , 300 ,300);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        StackPane layout = new StackPane();

        primaryStage.setTitle("Kuristo: PT Test Admin System");
        primaryStage.setMinWidth(1280);
        primaryStage.setMinHeight(900);
        primaryStage.centerOnScreen();

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("/styles/main.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        Rectangle2D screenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
        primaryStage.setX((screenBounds.getWidth() - primaryStage.getWidth()) / 2);
        primaryStage.setY((screenBounds.getHeight() - primaryStage.getHeight()) / 2);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Just for an updated answer, I chose to implement centering after the window is shown.

Comment: But the question explicitly aims at "before displaying it"