# JavaFX window opens in top left corner then jumps to center

Tags: java, javafx, kotlin, tornadofx

I'm developing a program in JavaFX (more specifically FornadoFX because I write it in Kotlin). What I've noticed is that when main window opens it initially in top left corner and then it jumps to the center.

This is how I start the application: `launch<MainWindowClass>(args)`

And this is my `start` method:

```
override fun start(stage: Stage) {
    with(stage){
        minWidth = 600.0
        minHeight = 250.0

        //Making it appear in the center
        val screenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().visualBounds
        x = screenBounds.width / 2 - minWidth / 2
        y = screenBounds.height / 2 - minHeight / 2
        scene = Scene(Group(), minWidth, minHeight)

        super.start(this)
    }
}
```

Central part (lines from `val screenBounds...` to `scene = ...`) have been based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29350971/4903564) answer.

However no matter if they are or not there the window always opens in top left and then jumps to set position, rather then being first shown there in the first place.

**EDIT:**

This is the minimal working example of the bug:

```
import javafx.scene.Group
import javafx.scene.Scene
import javafx.stage.Screen
import javafx.stage.Stage
import tornadofx.*

class MainWindow: App(MainView::class) {

    class MainView: View() {
        override val root = label("A window")
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic fun main(args: Array<String>){
            launch<MainWindow>(args)
        }
    }

    override fun start(stage: Stage) {
        with(stage){
            minWidth = 600.0
            minHeight = 250.0

            val screenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().visualBounds
            x = screenBounds.width / 2 - minWidth / 2
            y = screenBounds.height / 2 - minHeight / 2

            scene = Scene(Group(), minWidth, minHeight)

            super.start(this)
        }
    }
}
```

Also some info about system:
Java version: 11
Operating system: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Please post a _complete_ runnable app that exhibits this behavior :)

Comment: @EdvinSyse I did it. As you can see there is not much going on outside `start` method

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53351433/3956070), not the same issue, but has the same root cause.

Comment: @JoséPereda Thank you. This indeed solved the problem. Thanks :)
You can post it in the comment so that I could mark it as a solution

Comment: Ok, I've added it as an answer, and doing so I've noticed that the issue might have been already solved, so maybe you could try JavaFX 13-ea+11?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different issues have been reported for Linux and JavaFX 11, and some of them share the same root cause: the change from GTK 2 to GTK 3.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53351433/3956070) already explains it in detail.

As for the Windows issue, it has been already filed [here](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/issues/217), and it has been [fixed](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/pull/446/), so probably you could try JavaFX 13-ea+11 to test it.

In the meantime, or if you have to stick to a released JavaFX 11/12 version, the only workaround is the one suggested in the mentioned answer: run the app with GTK 2, that can be set with the system property:

```
java -Djdk.gtk.version=2
```

Comment: Thanks it solves the issue :) . As JavaFX 13 is still in early access I'll wait until it's released.

Comment: Good to know, the next release is barely just a month away